# Error: Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got InMemoryUploadedFile

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the above error when trying to upload multiple pictures from react to django rest api.
This is my django view code:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    posts_serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.FILES.getlist('image[]'), many=True)
    print(posts_serializer)

    if posts_serializer.is_valid():
        posts_serializer.save()
        return Response(posts_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        print('error', posts_serializer.errors)
        return Response(posts_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is a print from posts_serializer:

```
PostSerializer(data=[<InMemoryUploadedFile: 1PSM Logo.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: Microsoft-Azure-Fundamentals.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: DP-900_ProductImage-1.png (image/png)>], many=True):
            id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
            image = ImageField(max_length=100)
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove `getlist('image[]')` and try

Comment: Could you show us you PostSerializer ? (With DRF, you are supposed to use request.data, not request.FILES)

Comment: @Ahtisham Thank you, I removed getlist() and switched FILES to data. It now runs without error, but files are not uploaded in folder. Also I get 'Not Found: /cgi-bin/ Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 59366)' in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally made it work by using a different way:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        allimages = request.FILES.getlist('images')
        for oneimage in allimages:
            Post.objects.create(images=oneimage)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class Post(models.Model):
images = models.FileField(upload_to='post_images', default='')
```